# How to interrupt the passwd command?

Tags: command-line, kill, passwd

When I type `passwd`, I get

```
Changing password for <user>.
(current) UNIX password:
```

Now suppose at this point I change my mind and I decide to stay with my old password. What should I do?

`Ctrl` + `C` doesn't work. The only way I found is to use a second command line to find out the PID or the running `passwd` process and then feed it to `kill -9` (the standard `kill` doesn't work either).

Is there a better way, preferably not involving a second command line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found the best way to kill su during entering of an incorrect password is Control+U followed by Control+D. This should avoid annoying delays. You can also just clear the input with Control+U and re-try typing the password in.

Comment: interesting, this indeed works. can you explain what the effect of ctrl+U and ctrl+D is?

Answer (score 14):

`passwd` has switched the terminal in completely raw mode --- it will simply read everything you throw at it, included your `Ctrl`-`C` and the normally connected to "stop and go background" `Ctrl`-`Z`.

The best strategy is simply press `Enter` and wait for the error:

```
[romano:~] 10 % passwd                                               
Changing password for romano.
(current) UNIX password: 
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
```

Comment: If you decide to abort after providing your password in the first step, then just type mismatching passwords.